# What is this "sl-processed" code do in a link?

Tags: html, wordpress

I see a CMS (Wordpress) external links are coded with `sl-processed=1`. I guess this is not a not follow code or tracking link. what is the use of this code?

```
<a href="http://example.com/link-to-page/" target="_blank" sl-processed="1"> Page Title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apple affiliate code `itunes_autolinkmaker.js` script adds this attribute to all links when it upgrades all appropriate links to contain an affiliate code.

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/auto_link_maker/